# RewriteRule required for URL's with 2 query parameters

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

```
theyouthtalent.com/user_wall.php?User=khalidmirza&Talent=Business
```

I want to rewrite and redirect above mentioned URL like

```
http://theyouthtalent.com/Business/khalidmirza
```

where Business >> Talent=Business and khalidmirza >> User=khalidmirza

right now I am using these below mentinoed rules which are fine for
    http://theyouthtalent.com/khalidmirza

but I want to include Talent (Business) before User (khalidmirza)

Kindly propose change in below rules to get desire result.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ user_wall.php?User=$1&Talent=$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} user_wall\.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} User=(\w+)&Talent=(\w+)
RewriteRule ^user_wall\.php$ /%1? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex to capture 2 components isn't correct in the rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /user_wall\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^User=(\w+)&Talent=(\w+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^user_wall\.php$ /%2/%1? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/?$ user_wall.php?User=$2&Talent=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: What URL is giving 404? Where is this .htaccess located?

Comment: your suggested rules rewriting and redirecting in this format
http://theyouthtalent.com/khalidmirza/Business
but I need this in this format
http://theyouthtalent.com/Business/khalidmirza

Comment: its working but did't rendering css and images
http://theyouthtalent.com/Business/farasatali

Comment: Oh for CSS/js etc just make sure to use absolute URL I.e. starting with http:// or / or use `<base href="/">` in your page's head section.

Comment: css/images are loading now but 2 other problems are 

1) when accessing user_wall.php based url its working but in same page there is link with view.php?.... giving 404 error
http://theyouthtalent.com/Business/view.php?User=farasatali&Talent=Business%20&Section=Photos
i think it should be add as RewriteCond and look like http://theyouthtalent.com/Business/farasatali/Photos

2)while at http://theyouthtalent.com/Business/farasatali
this page when click on logo (left top) to bring user at home page it return url http://theyouthtalent.com/Business/home.php

kindly guide me to fix these two issue

Comment: Your question is about handling `/user_wall.php` and my answer is for the requirement. If you want to ask a new question feel free to create a new one after marking this one as accepted since this has worked for you.